# Was this edit rejected? Why wasn't I notified?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits, notifications

Earlier this evening, I suggested an edit to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429835/composition-of-rotation-matrix-how) which was much like this:

[image]

I'm posting this screenshot in case this duplicate edit gets rejected too. Because it seems my previous one was. Indeed, I was waiting for notifs on that edit, pretty sure it would be accepted since the English of that post («I am the moment learning about rotation matrices, at which seems to confusing me how this is possible») was simply terrible, and I'm pretty sure that displayed formula is much better displayed than not, though I didn't display it in the edit we are discussing.

So I'm asking: what became of this edit? Was it rejected? Was it reviewed at all? And most importantly, why did the «Thanks for your edit!» banner vanish without any notifs being given to me about actions taken on the edit, when it clearly wasn't accepted and I had to remake it?

PS The [duplicate edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/478610) got accepted, confirming my opinion it was a good one. It was identical to the one in question, save for «ie.» being left where it was and the equation not being displayed. Oh, and no colon being added after «possible».

PPS OK, maybe it's not good practice to make duplicate edits, but then this really needed to be done IMHO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Users are not notified of rejected or accepted edit suggestions. (However, they [may receive a warning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137334) at the time of a future submission).

The [suggestions](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/135592/mickg?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) tab of your profile lists them, clearly indicating which were rejected.

Clicking "rejected edit" leads to [review transcript](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/478579) where you can see who rejected and what reason they picked.

In my opinion, the edit was valid and the rejection was a mistake.

Comment: [More info](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137334/269069) about notifications regarding edits.

Comment: Thanks, added that to the answer. (By "not notified", I meant there is no  inbox notification.
)